# table rows are not properly aligned with table header in IE

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ngtable

I am facing issue when working with **NgTableParams** to show table in **IE**.
It is showing correctly in chrome but the table row alignment is not proper in IE.
Please find the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/NAi4ZIleQ2LWDWHQbjS5?p=preview

In IE when you open the above link and Launch the preview window in separate page, you can notice the **table rows are not properly matching with the table header**.Any inputs?

html:

```
<div  ng-controller="BaseController">

    <div class="col-xs-5 container-paragraph">
        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped table-scroll" show-filter="true">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                <td title="'Name'" filter="{ firstname: 'text'}" sortable="'firstname'">
                    {{user.firstname}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 container-paragraph">
        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped table-scroll" show-filter="true">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                <td title="'Name'" filter="{ firstname: 'text'}" sortable="'firstname'">
                    {{user.firstname}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pls find the image which shows the alignment of rows with the header issue in IE below:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put both tables inside a single table and try

Comment: @bhaumik shah - i dont want to create search button separately.. is there any way to keep use sam table structure as i used but align the tabl header with table rows by modifying css code.

Answer (score 0):

may this code help you

```
 <td data-title="'#'" sortable="'id'">
                        {{$index + 1}} </td>
```

you can name your fields using data-title in ng-table

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm pull-right ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" 
                       ng-model="" placeholder="">
```

and search button seperatelly